# Apache htaccess Rewrite rule to append querystring to all css files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to append a static query string to all css files on my site. Like styles.css to styles.css?a=1. Is it possible to achieve this through rewrite rules in .htaccess file. If so what's the rewrite rule to be written. thanks in advance. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to the .htaccess file under the root folder of your website, this will this redirect all css requests to the css?a=34 (query shown in the user browser), is that what you want?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ $1.css?a=34 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm pretty novoice in this stuff so I guess this needs to be written in the .htaccess file : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ $1.css?a=1 [L]
</IfModule> but this isn't working. .

Comment: does the code above works ? if not , are you getting an error?

Comment: thanks this works :) but unfortunately doesn't solves my problem. I guessed that doing so will force the browser to reload the css files, every time a new version is released. Any idea on how to achieve this??